# Implement KNN to find nearest color?

Tags: pandas, image, machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision

I have a bunch of data with two columns: a label for a given an object, and the color of that object (a list containing [R, G, B]) values. Is there an efficient way to make a function that tells me the object most similar to a color a user enters? This seems like a candidate for KNN.

How would I do this in Python, preferably using SciKit? And is there anything I can do implement KNN more efficiently as I have about 10,000 observations?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
       "Object": ["A", "B", "C", "A"],
       "Color": [[100, 120, 120], [50, 75, 50], [60, 70, 100], [90, 150, 200]]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

candidate = [50, 40, 90]

def nearest_match(df, candidate):
  # something

  return nearest_match
```

Answer (score 2):

```
X = [[100, 120, 120], [50, 75, 50], [60, 70, 100], [90, 150, 200]]
y = ["A", "B", "C", "A"]
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=4)
neigh.fit(X, y) 

print(neigh.predict([[100, 100, 100]]))
```

To make it perform better you can choose what metric you want to use for the distance. Also, choose which algo you want to use.

You can also go implementing it from scratch using this [tutorial](https://www.python-course.eu/k_nearest_neighbor_classifier.php). Probably out of the box libraries are better to use since they are optimised.

If implementing in C is an option you can take that route. Or go with Cythonsing parts of your implementation.

P.s. Might be worthwhile to finetune the number of neighbours.

Comment: No matter what value is provided to neigh.predict() it always returns ['A']. Can you tell why?

Comment: If you give to the predict function as a sample as follows 
```print(neigh.predict([[50, 75, 50]]))``` it would output the label "B". The model has already encountered such label during the training. The whole point is that if you give it enough samples the clusters will be formed accurately. Later on, when you try to classify a new example, the produced label would fall in one of the established categories during the training. You can also try giving it ```[50, 70, 50]]```. Maybe you need to do a bit more reading about the topic. If you found my answer useful in any way please upvote.